# Put cursor at the end of selected block after some operation

Tags: vim

Couple of examples that I encounter quite often.

#### Indenting some code

E.g. I want to put code block inside `if` statement:

```
puts("hello");
puts("world");
```

I enter `if (pid > 0) {` before the first line, then press <kbd>Esc</kbd>,<kbd>j</kbd>,<kbd>Shift+v</kbd>,<kbd>j</kbd>,<kbd>></kbd>:

```
if (pid > 0) {
  puts("hello");
  puts("world");
```

Now cursor is at the beginnig of the first `puts` and to enter closing bracket I need one extra <kbd>j</kbd> to go to the end of the indented block.

#### Pasting block and adding to end of it

Almost the same example. When extracting some code to function, after pasting it with <kbd>p</kbd> I need to append return statement or closing bracket at the end. If I'm lucky there will be empty line after pasted block and I can use <kbd>}</kbd> to jump right there, but it's not always the case.

#### Question

So the question is how to jump to the end of the selected block after some operation performed on it (pasting, indenting, etc)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
`]
```

Will move you to the end of yanked or previously changed text.

See

```
:h `]
```

Comment: vimgolf answer: After you type the if statement execute the following: `p=']']o}<esc>`. `p=']` will paste and indent text. You may also want to take a look at `:h ]p`

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative behaviour, you could insert the closing `}` first and *then* indent the code inside the new scope automatically.

Being at the last line of the new scope in normal mode:

> <kbd>o</kbd><kbd>}</kbd><kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>%</kbd><kbd>=</kbd>